# How do you run the server to use/test the JSON format?

Tags: rule-engine, durable-rules

The Reference Manuak at https://github.com/jruizgit/rules/blob/master/docs/json/reference.md says that I can assert facts like this:

```
curl -H "content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"subject": "Tweety", "predicate": "eats", "object": "worms"}' http://localhost:5000/animal/facts
```

But how I run the server at port 5000? Does durable_rules comes with a built in HTTP Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for asking the question. The JSON doc is outdated. durable_rules V2, no longer starts an http server (which gives you the flexibility to choose how you want to host your rulesets). You can provide a JSON document as follows:

```py
from durable.lang import *

def callback(c):
    print('risk7 fraud detected')

get_host().set_rulesets({ 'risk7': {
    'suspect': {
        'run': callback,
        'all': [
            {'first': {'t': 'purchase'}},
            {'second': {'$neq': {'location': {'first': 'location'}}}}
        ],
    }
}})

post('risk7', {'t': 'purchase', 'location': 'US'});
post('risk7', {'t': 'purchase', 'location': 'CA'});
```